# Go module path resolution

Tags: go, go-modules

I currently have a Go project (gRPC microservice) which has a nested module that exports the generated gRPC code. The following is the structure of this project:

```
/cmd
- main.go
/internal
- pkg1/
-- pkg1.go
go.mod
go.sum
/api
- /proto
  - /v1
    - hello.proto
- /gen
  - go.mod
  - go.sum
  - /v1
    - hello.pb.go
    - hello_grpc.pb.go
```

Reason being I am looking to publish the generated proto & gRPC code as a Go module so that other microservices can use them. For example, this repo is hosted at `github.com/myOrg/service`

`api/gen/go.mod` :

```
module github.com/myOrg/service/grpc

go 1.18
```

I have pushed a release successfully with the tag `grpc/v0.0.1`. However, when I do `go list -m -versions github.com/myOrg/service/grpc`, I get the following error:

```
go: loading module retractions for github.com/myOrg/service/grpc@v0.0.1: version "v0.0.1" invalid: missing github.com/myOrg/service/grpc/go.mod at revision grpc/v0.0.1
```

Is this because go list is expecting the nested module to be at `github.com/myOrg/service/grpc` when instead it is at `github.com/myOrg/service/api/gen` ? If so, is the only workaround to put the generated code at `github.com/myOrg/service/grpc` or is there a way to make the module `github.com/myOrg/service/grpc` resolve to `github.com/myOrg/service/api/gen` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Go Modules Reference](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-dir), yes, the module `github.com/myOrg/service/grpc` should be located in the subdirectory `grpc` and there is not a workaround to make it resolve to the subdirectory `api/gen`. Here is the doc (with the parts related to this question highlighted):

> #### Module directories within a repository
>
> Once a module’s repository has been checked out at a specific revision, the go command must locate the directory that contains the module’s go.mod file (the module’s root directory).
>
> Recall that a [module path](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path) consists of three parts: a repository root path (corresponding to the repository root directory), **a module subdirectory**, and a major version suffix (only for modules released at v2 or higher).
>
> For most modules, the module path is equal to the repository root path, so the module’s root directory is the repository’s root directory.
>
> Modules are sometimes defined in repository subdirectories. This is typically done for large repositories with multiple components that need to be released and versioned independently. **Such a module is expected to be found in a subdirectory that matches the part of the module’s path after the repository root path**. For example, suppose the module example.com/monorepo/foo/bar is in the repository with root path example.com/monorepo. Its go.mod file **must be** in the foo/bar subdirectory.